# Installation through npm getting stuck, It hangs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I know this issue has been asked multiple time at various places but none of them is working. Things I have tried:

1. npm config rm proxy
2. npm config rm https-proxy
3. npm cache verify
4. With NPM, NODE (6.14.6, 12.16.3): stuck at

   [..........] /rollbackfailedoptional
   Err: ETIMEDOUT
5. Upgrading NODE 12.16.3->15.5 and NPM 6.14.6->7.3: stuck at

   [.......] /idealTree:weather: sill idealTree builddeps
6. npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
7. Tried removing package-lock.json
8. I have enabled loglevel to info; restarted device multiple times

Currently the snapshot of latest run is here. It was all working then it stucked. I am able to access sites on chrome. Working on Ubuntu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB04y.png

Answer (score 0):

Connection was using Mobile USB tethering using 4G mobile connection. Though websites were opening in browser, I dont know why it failed to download packages from npm. All the said solutions were done but luckily it didnt break y installation.
I switched from 4G mobile connection to wifi though still on USB tethering and it worked with new versions of NPM and NODEJS.
Finally, it seems problem was related to connection after all. 'NPM' may need continuous reliable connection with minimal packet loss and browser might have worked with more packet losses.